# jenkins ci init.d script returns error when queried for status

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, centos, init.d

I'm using the following init.d script courtesy of the jenkins ci website https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JenkinsLinuxStartupScript

It works fine when I start and stop jenkins, but when I ask for status it gives an error. How can I make it report status correctly?

```
[root@jenkins01 init.d]# service jenkins start
Starting Tomcat: Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.54
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.54
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13
Using CLASSPATH:       /apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat- \ 
7.0.54/bin/bootstrap.jar:/apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /apps/tomcat/jenkins-tomcat.pid
Tomcat started.

[root@jenkins01 init.d]# service jenkins status
status: Unknown job: tomcat

[root@jenkins01 init.d]# cat /apps/tomcat/jenkins-tomcat.pid
8919
```

Here the script in full, slightly tailored to my setup:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Startup script for the Jenkins Continuous Integration server
# (via Jakarta Tomcat Java Servlets and JSP server)
#
# chkconfig: - 85 15
# description: Jakarta Tomcat Java Servlets and JSP server
# processname: tomcat
# pidfile: /var/run/tomcat.pid

# Set Tomcat environment.
JENKINS_USER=tomcat
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/jenkins
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export HOME=/apps/tomcat
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13
export JENKINS_BASEDIR=/apps/tomcat
export TOMCAT_HOME=/apps/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.54
export CATALINA_PID=$JENKINS_BASEDIR/jenkins-tomcat.pid
export CATALINA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_BASEDIR/jenkins-home -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"

[ -f $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh ] || exit 0

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
        # Start daemon.
        echo -n "Starting Tomcat: "
        su -p -s /bin/sh $JENKINS_USER -c "$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start"
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch $LOCKFILE
        ;;
  stop)
        # Stop daemons.
        echo -n "Shutting down Tomcat: "
        su -p -s /bin/sh $JENKINS_USER -c "$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop"
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f $LOCKFILE
        ;;
  restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
  condrestart)
       [ -e $LOCKFILE ] && $0 restart
       ;;
  status)
        status tomcat
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issues as you, the script on the website is just plain wrong, I have updated it (I tested on Red Hat).

The errors were:

- missing source of functions library (without it the status command was used instead of the status function defined in the library)

  `# Source function library.
  . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`
- wrong processname in description (tomcat instead of jenkins)
- wrong pidfile in description
- incorrect status syntax, correct:
  `status -p $CATALINA_PID -l $(basename $LOCKFILE) jenkins`